# How to pass view data to controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I want to create sample web app using php mvc but don't know how to pass view data (login.php) to controller (userController.php)

My view (login.php)

```
<body>
    <form action="userController/getLogin" method="post" name="login">
    </form>
</body>
```

controller (userController.php)

```
<?php
include "../user.php";
include "connection.php";
class Controller {
    public $model;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = new Model();
    }

    public function getLogin()
    {
        $result=$this->model->getLogin();

        if($reslt == 'login')
        {
            include 'view/Afterlogin.php';
        }
        else
        {
            include 'view/login.php';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

How do I call this action?

Comment: this is an outright off-topic, totally ignoring what Programmers is **[about](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour)**. Why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow, are you question blocked there? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: Use URL rewriting. And then you could resolve/parse it to the controller action. Google may also help you at this point, because many frameworks do it that way.

Comment: its done ...create a router.php file to get data from URL thanks.  #alpham8